# Possibility of sending a string from .jsp to a .java class from user input?

Tags: java, jsp, httprequest, user-input

UPDATE: I forgot to add my **GotApp.java**

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class GotApp extends HttpServlet {
  static DatabaseConn connection = null;
  static UserStore    dataStore  = null;
  static TaskCoderWtc coder      = null;
  ServletContext servletContext = null;
  static String       coderApp   = null;
  static String       workDir    = null;

  public void init() {
  try {
    servletContext = getServletContext();
    coderApp       = getParameter("tricon.proxy"); //exists in web.xml
    workDir        = getParameter("data.dir"); //exists in web.xml
    dataStore      = new UserStore(workDir); //exists in web.xml
    }
  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
  throws IOException, ServletException {
  doPost(req, resp);
  }

  public UserStore getDataStore() {
  return dataStore;
  }
  public DatabaseConn getConnection() { // FIXME This needs a better name.
  return connection;
  }

  String getParameter(String str) throws Exception {
  if (servletContext == null) {
    throw new Exception("servletContext is null.");
    return servletContext.getInitParameter(str);
  }

  public User getUser(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
  throws ServletException {
  // We only really need req.
  return dataStore.loadUser(getUsername(req));
  }

  // Will never return null.
  public Task getTask(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    User user = getUser(req, resp);
    //if (user == null) {
    //  return null;
    //}
    String taskname = req.getParameter("taskname");
    Task task = new Task(taskname);
    // Make a quick check here.
    if (task.isCoding()) {
      resp.sendRedirect("task.jsp?" + req.getQueryString());
    }
    user.addTask(task);
    return task;
  }

  public String getAction(HttpServletRequest req) {
  String action = req.getParameter("action");
  if (action == null) {
    action = "";
   }
  return action.toLowerCase();
  }
```

I have a web page that asks a user to choose 4 options which will be stored as a string respective to the choice. This is located in my **htmltask.java**:

```
import com.nav.wtc.model.coder.TaskRunner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import helper.DatabaseConn;
import helper.UserStore;
import pages.GotApp;

public class HtmlTask extends GotApp {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.doPost(req, resp);

    UserStore    dataStore  = getDataStore();
    DatabaseConn connection = getConnection();
    TaskRunner   runner     = getTaskRunner();

    Task   task       = getTask(req, resp);
    String action     = getAction(req);

    resp.getWriter().println(showPage(task));
}

    public String showPage(Task task) {
      StringBufn sb   = new StringBufn();
      sb.add("<html>");
      sb.add("<body>");
      sb.add(showCall(task));
      sb.add("</body>
      sb.add("</html>
      return sb.toString();
    }
    private String showCall(Task task) {
    StringBufn sb = new StringBufn();
    sb.add("<div class='area'>");
    sb.add("<form method='get' action='task.jsp'>");
    sb.add("  <table>");
    sb.add("    <tr class='1'>");
    sb.add("      <td>");
    sb.add(" What level would you like to code to: <br> ");
    sb.add("  <input type ='radio' name='call' value='valsel'> Selections<br> ");
    sb.add(" <input type ='radio' name='call' value='valselpbd'> Parts<br> ");
    sb.add("  <input type ='radio' name='call' value='valselhbd'> Holes<br> ");
    sb.add("  <input type ='radio' name='call' value='valselrbd'> C-BOMs<br> ");
    sb.add("  <input type ='radio' name='call' value='valselpbdrbd'> BOMs<br> ");
    sb.add("       <input type='submit' value='Run Task' />");
    sb.add("      </td>");
    sb.add("    </tr>");
    sb.add("  </table>");
    sb.add("</form>");
    sb.add("</div>");
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

I would like to take one of the values here (which would be submitted by the user) and use that as input in another java class file called **TaskCoderImpl.java**:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream; // For debugging.
import java.io.FileOutputStream; // For debugging.
import java.io.OutputStream; // For debugging.
import java.io.InputStream; // For debugging.

void coder(File exe, File ord, File cod, File msg, File rls, String tcc )
        throws ProcessException {
    String[] cmd = {
            exe.getPath(),  // Executable
            ord.getPath(),  // InputOrder      (IN)
            cod.getPath(),  // ResultsCodedOrder (OUT)
            msg.getPath(),  // Messages   (OUT)
            rls.getPath(),  // Releases   (IN)
            tcc = ""
    };

Order codeOrder(File taskdir, Order order) throws ProcessException {
    String ordername = order.getName();

    // Create temp 'input' files.
    File orderFile   = createTriconOrderFile(taskdir, order);
    File releaseFile = createTriconReleaseFile(taskdir, order);

    // Define temp 'output' files.
    File messageFile = new File(taskdir, ordername + msgExt);
    File codedFile   = new File(taskdir, ordername + codExt);

    // Code order.
    coder(exe,
            orderFile,
            codedFile,
            messageFile,
            releaseFile,
            "USER 'value' INPUT");
return codedOrder;
}
```

Is it even possible for me to use the 'values' from htmltask.java (which contains the servlet ie. req, resp stuff) and use those 'values' as input in my TaskCoderImpl.java as it requires only a string...If so am I missing anything...I really hope I'm not confusing anyone...

UPDATE:
Adding **task.jsp**:

```
<%getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Task").forward(request, response);%>
```

Adding **web.xml** servlet style

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Task</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>pages.html.HtmlTask</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Task</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Task</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, you're asking if you can pass a String to a method in another class?

Comment: You confused me for sure. Why can't you call the TaskCoderImpl method inside your HtmlTask class and pass the string value you need to pass?

Comment: @RayStojonic yes that is exactly what i want but that string is coming from the html page in the form of 'name ="call"' with a value dependent on what is chosen by a user..

Comment: @SerotoninChase What I assume is going on is that in the htmltask class (which is associated to a task.jsp) is storing a value under the name 'call' (Correct me if i'm wrong)...I want TaskCoderImpl to use the value in the coder() method instead of the HtmlTask class using a 'hardcoded' value in TaskCoderImpl...hope that's a little clearer

Comment: Okay, this is a...um...less than standard way of doing things. That aside, in doPost check the request for a call parameter, eg: `String call = req.getParameter( "call" );` if `call` is not empty or null, pass it to your TaskCoderImpl. Please look into how to properly use JSPs with servlets, you'll save yourself much heartache.

Comment: @RayStojonic I'm working with a very old application right now and the developer didn't leave any documentation so I'm reinventing the wheel as a project for myself...Anyways, how do i pass it to TaskCoderImpl...Do i have to add packages to TaskCoderImpl to receive the parameter

Comment: Well, I don't really know, you haven't included any code for TaskCoderImpl that accepts a String parameter. Now, assuming `getTask(req, resp)` builds a Task out of parameters from the request, I would look there to see if you even need to extract this information (maybe it's already being done?) What I can see is that even though a Task is passed to `showPage` any content it might contain isn't being used. I'm still not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish...what I would do is pull the html out of the servlet, and use it to create an actual task.jsp and change the form action to `/Task`

Comment: @RayStojonic We could assume that htmlTask.java is task.jsp because this is being put forth into Tomcat version 5.5 (REALLY OLD)...should I make something similar to `getTask(req,resp)`...How would you update TaskCodeImpl.java to receive the parameter 'call' if it was available?

Comment: @koala421 I would add a private variable named 'call' and `getCall()` and `setCall()` to get and set the call value, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Well the task.jsp is just a java jsp file.  The request is an implicit object that the next page will have available.

And as such it will get the html form submission attributes and you can look at those and use them to do whatever.

```
<%=request.getParameter("call")%>
```

I think your parameter is 'call'?  Print the whole request and pick out the piece you need.

You can do it in EL also.

Hello, ${param.call}

You are making this loads harder by not using EL, jsf and or other more modern things.  There are tag libraries for the input box, etc.

Comment: If i add the code you are displaying to task.jsp how will TaskCoderImpl.java use the "call" parameter...Is there some 'trick' to inherit parameters in the coder method or do I have to import some servlet/jsp package within TaskCoderImpl class?